# Component/module for registering to get document

Tags: component, form, download

I'm looking for a way to have users register their email and then get sent a document, like you often see on sites offering white papers.

I've looked at many of the download extensions on the JED but all seems to be targeting allowing access to downloading selected files as from a repository. And that is *not* what I want. But rather something like one of the ones critiqued [here](https://instapage.com/blog/white-paper-landing-page-examples).

I've also looked at newsletter and registration extensions, and as far as I can tell, they mostly hook into MailChimp or some other newsletter/mailing solution.

One difference from a simple registration form is that I'd like the component to also provide the complimentary mail, including the white paper, or a personalized link to it.

Does such a Joomla extension exist? If not, any hints on customizing any of the other extensions, or building it myself, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a form that prompts for an email address and then provides a download link using most of the forms extensions available in Joomla. There are plenty of them available at https://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms

For example, [Convert Forms](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/convert-forms) and [Balbooa Forms Builder](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/forms) both have free and paid versions and are both available for Joomla 4.

Comment: Thanks. I already had ConvertForms, but now after looking more closely I found the ”PDF Form Submission Form” addon. I’ll try that.

Comment: Turned out that "PDF Form Submission" was not what I was looking for. But with a little help by tassos.gr I figured out that there was an option in Convert Forms for sending an email on submitting. So solved.

Answer (score 2):

Acymail is a very good extension that would allow you to register/collect email addresses and you can then send one or more follow up emails which could be your document or have your document attached as a .pdf

https://www.acymailing.com/

It is quite a powerful and mature product that has since been ported across to Wordpress and it is stand alone installation on your Joomla site and doesn't require other services such as Mail chimp, but can use them if you need the anti-spam or high delivery rates.

It also integrates well with a number of other good Joomla extensions such as form builders and e Commerce so you may find it useful for other purposes as well.

Comment: This is very obviously a newsletter manager (which I explicitly said I didn’t want). I could not find a way to respond to a registration with a personalized PDF or link either.